# How to use Scroll from Source without mouse but keyboard in PhpStorm?

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

PhpStorm offers the functionality to "Scroll from Source", which shows the current open file in the Project's sidepanel like so:

Before click, the `src` folder is closed in sidebar, `MailerFactory.php` is open in editor's panel.

[image: Before click scroll from source]

After click, sidebar has opened and selected the `MailerFactory.php` class in sidebar.

[image: After click with located source file]

I don't want to use the mouse for this action, yet I am unable to find it in the keymap nor when I search for all actions using <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd> (aka: "Enter action name or option name").

I can I scroll from source using the keyboard only?

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for that option (yes, that's an option of Project View panel and not actual action).

But you can use this one instead: **Navigate | Select In... | Project View** (<kbd>Alt+F1, 1</kbd> using Default keymap).

[image]